# Disable line highlighting in terminal

Tags: terminal-emacs

I'm currenty using emacs line highlighting and I found it useful when doing my work in GUI version of emacs. However, I find it uncomfortable to have such mode during my work in terminal. The color of higlight there makes current line being edited almost impossible to read.

The line in my `.emacs` file which is responsible for enabling this mode globally is: `(global-hl-line-mode t)`.

**My question is:** is there a way to disable `hl-line-mode` only in terminal? I'm using xfce4-terminal and guake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable highlight mode only in gui version of emacs by wrapping the command inside if window-system.

The value of the window system variable is nil incase of terminals

```
(if window-system (global-hl-line-mode t))
```

Reference https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Systems.html

NOTE : use **`(display-graphic-p)`**  instead of `window-system`. For more information refer the comments by Drew.

Comment: FWIW: Emacs Dev generally recommends that we use **`display-graphic-p`** now, instead of `window-system`. I can't give you the reasons why. See the Elisp manual, node [Display Feature Testing](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Feature-Testing.html).

Comment: @Drew Thanks. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you guys. I don't really know why I had to use `(display-graphic-p)` (with brackets) but `window-system` (without brackets). Nonetheless, both solutions seem to work fine.

Comment: @threaz: That's because the older `window-system` is a single variable that tells if there is a window system for the original frame of emacs.  `display-graphic-p` is a function that can tell you if a particular frame is graphical.  With emacs-client/server, you can actually have frames on both graphic and text-only displays.